# AOSP/LineageOS Intellij/Android Studio importing

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, makefile, android-source

I recently cloned the AOSP to make some modification and fiddle around.
The first thing i tried editing was the SystemUI, my problem is that in pretty much every class of the AOSP there are errors.

I successfully run `idegen.sh`, also added an JDK and removed all jars, adjusted the custom vm properties in Intellij/Android Studio, marked `out/target/common/R` as source, and i was also able to build an image using the `m` command, and run it on my emulator afterwards.

So the only problem is not being able to edit code correctly.

For example:

```
String appName = system
                ? context.getString(com.android.internal.R.string.notification_app_name_system)
                : context.getString(com.android.internal.R.string.notification_app_name_settings);
        extras.putString(Notification.EXTRA_SUBSTITUTE_APP_NAME, appName);
```

(Taken from com.android.systemui.SystemUI line 57)

Intellij cannot resolve `R` or `EXTRA_SUBSTITUTE_APP_NAME` looking into the source, `EXTRA_SUBSTITUTE_APP_NAME` is marked with a `/** @hide */` comment.

```
/** @hide */
    @SystemApi
    @RequiresPermission(android.Manifest.permission.SUBSTITUTE_NOTIFICATION_APP_NAME)
    public static final String EXTRA_SUBSTITUTE_APP_NAME = "android.substName";
```

AOSP Link (Line: 1312): https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Notification.java

I really hope that there is a better way editing the AOSP than "deal with the errors".

Some quick stats:

- Java-Version: 11.0.11
- Intellij-Version: 2021.2
- AOSP-Version: Android-11
- Lunch-Device: aosp_x86_64-eng
- OS: PopOS 21.04 (Ubuntu 21.04)

Thanks for replies :)!

Comment: Did you build it at least once so that R is generated ?

Comment: I used the m command and was able to start the emulator afterwards, is that what you mean? Or you mean an build within intellij?

Comment: Yeah, I meant a full make ( with "make" or "m" command, its the same ), not with IntelliJ.

Comment: Yeah sadly no success with that, the build worked fine but Intellij still throws tons of errors sadly :/